# Limit maximum number of table rows using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am using following code to generate a dynamic input table. How to limit maximum input rows to 10?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="idetails[]' + counter + '"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="idate[]' + counter + '"></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="iamount[]' + counter + '"></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="delrow btn btn-danger"  value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table").append(newRow);
        counter++;
    });

    $("table").on("click", ".delrow", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        counter -= 1
    });
});
```

Comment: set the condition of the counter like if(counter <=10) then append otherwise it will give an error msg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `minimum` and `maximum` limit when you are `appending` the rows

This will will ensure you are **NOT** `duplicating` your code you can use the `Min_Input` as your `counter` and for `deleting` the `tr's` as well.

**Live Full Working Demo:**

```js
var Max_fields = 10; //set maximum
var Min_Input = 0; //set minimum
$("#addrow").on("click", function() {
  var newRow = $("<tr>");
  var cols = "";

  cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="idetails[]' + Min_Input + '"></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="idate[]' + Min_Input + '"></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="iamount[]' + Min_Input + '"></td>';
  cols += '<td><input type="button" class="delrow btn btn-danger"  value="Delete"></td>';
  newRow.append(cols);

  if (Min_Input < Max_fields) {
    Min_Input++; //increase counter
    $("table").append(newRow); //append rows
  } else {
    alert('limit reached')
  }
});

$("table").on("click", ".delrow", function(event) {
  $(this).closest("tr").remove();
   Min_Input -= 1 //decrease counter
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
<button id="addrow">Add</button>
```

Comment: Perfect!. This is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Nirjhar Glad to help you. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest such a code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var counter = 0;
    
        $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
            var newRow = $("<tr>");
            var cols = "";
    
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="idetails[]' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="date" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="idate[]' + counter + '"></td>';
            cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="iamount[]' + counter + '"></td>';
    
            cols += '<td><input type="button" class="delrow btn btn-danger"  value="Delete"></td>';
       if(counter<=10)
           {
            newRow.append(cols);
            $("table").append(newRow);
              counter++;
           }
            
        });
    
        $("table").on("click", ".delrow", function (event) {
            $(this).closest("tr").remove();
            counter -= 1
        });
    });
```